# Can't use JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs in rust

Tags: java, rust, memory, linker, java-native-interface

this is my java code:

```java
public class HelloWorld {

    public void rust_invoke() {

        String msg = "Hello from rust!";

        System.out.println(msg);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String msg = "Hello from java!";

        while(true) {

            System.out.println(msg);

            try {

                // Sleep for 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds)

                Thread.sleep(3000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

and I want to inject a rust dll into it and run rust_invoke()

here is my rust code:

```rs
use jni::sys::{JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs, JavaVM};

use toy_arms::internal;

internal::create_entrypoint!(start);

fn start() {

    let mut vms = Vec::new();

    get_created_java_vms(&mut vms);

}

fn get_created_java_vms(vm_buf: &mut Vec<*mut JavaVM>) {

    unsafe {

        JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(vm_buf.as_mut_ptr(), 0, std::ptr::null_mut());

    }

}
```

if I get the JavaVM everything should be fine and I can now do whatever I want with that Java program but I get the worst kind of error... linker error

```
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1120
client.client.699f8466d7fc073f-cgu.0.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs referenced in function _ZN3std10sys_common9backtrace28__rust_begin_short_backtrace17h63d927efea3d5a74E
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I tried changing linker and switched from nightly to stable added every java header to path and LD_LIBRARY_PATH but still the same error

also I'm on windows and using jdk 20

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to add this to build.rs

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=/path/to/java/lib");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=jvm");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for misreading, continued from comments

---

jni::sys was written for internal use, do not use it.

jni is an interface for using native binaries in java.

In java, you can use

```java
static {
  System.load("/Path/to/so/or/dll.dll");
  System.loadLibrary("nameOfLibraryWithoutExtension");
}
```

to load it.

If you want to use native function in java, you can use

```java
  private(or public) native (returnType) (functionName)(args);
  private native void myFunc2();
  ...
  void foo() {
    var ret = (name)(1,2,3);
    myFunc2();
  }
```

---

In this case, you can use `javap -s compiled.class.path` to descripter,

after than, write this code,

```rust
#[export_name = "function_symbol_from_header_made_by_javac_h_option"]
fn myFunc<'local>(mut env: JNIEnv<'local>, class: JClass<'local>) {
  env.call_method(&class, "rust_invoke", "(descriptor from javap -s)", &[JValueGen::Void]).unwrap();
}
#[export_name = "Java_com_eveheeero_example_TestClass_myFunc2"]
fn myFunc<'local>(mut env: JNIEnv<'local>, class: JClass<'local>, arg1: JClass<'local>) -> jobject /* return type must be () or jobject or jint or ... that all char is lowercase in jni */ {
  // example for arg 1 method, call exampleMethod(int), return class object
  env.call_method(&class, "exampleMethod2", "(I)V" /* (Arg)Return */, &[JValueGen::Int(1)]).unwrap(); // if you want to object pointer, you can use into_raw() method after unwrap()
  env.new_string("empty return").unwrap().into_raw()
}
```

---

Here's the order of use for jni.

1. define name of library.
2. define name of function.
3. write function interface in java. (using native...)
4. compile java class first, javac -h . PathToJavaSource to generate header
5. with header, you can guess function symbol to use
6. with that function symbol, write rust function with no_mangle or export_name
7. compile with cdylib
8. run java class

Comment: Yes I tried that and that works but it's not what I'm looking for I want to inject my code so the Java program doesn't know that that's going to happen I have dll injector and I was able to inject a rust function into it but I want to call a Java function from it

Comment: @NightmareXD had you tried this? https://docs.rs/jni/0.21.1/jni/struct.JavaVM.html 
add path $JAVA_HOME/bin or can use with_libjvm

Comment: Yes but my Java program will be started using java command and it's not going to get started from rust so this doesn't work and I have to use from_raw which I need to use JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs to get the pointers also JAVA_HOME is set and bin is in PATH

Comment: @NightmareXD I'm success with JavaVM

Comment: when I call rust function from jvm, new JavaVM was not working, it seems to be designed that way,
when I make rust exe program, and generate JavaVm, attache CurrentThread, call staticMethod, no "Hello from java" called, and was "hello from rust" called

Comment: could you upload the rust's code that uses javavm?

Comment: Its the same one in the docs